# split a column value into multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement when I have to split a column value into multiple rows, the column value is not delaminated, it is just text. Each row must not have more than a certain number of characters.

my table just one column.

```
               Value 
       This is the text for test.
```

Now I want to have the above value in maximum length of 5 characters in one row but multiple rows.

```
ID    Value 
 1    This        (this row has a white space in the end)
 2    is the
 3     text       (this row has a white space in the beginning)
 4    for t
 5    est.        (this row has only 4 character but not more than5 )
```

Comment: What did you try? Show us your work.

Comment: I tried the case statement when LEN(Value) >= 5 THEN.. but it seems to return only one row, I need multiple rows. I am sorry my attempt is so poor I don't want to embarrass myself :(

Comment: I have been looking online and every solution on the web seems to talk about splitting values on some sort of delimiter, my delimiter is the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select left(col, 5) as char5, substring(col, 6, len(col)) as rest
      from table t
      union all
      select left(rest, 5), substring(rest, 6, len(rest))
      from cte
      where len(rest) > 0
     )
select char5
from cte;
```

Note that there is a maximum recursion depth in SQL Server.  You can override the default if the strings are really long.

Comment: Thank you for your response, my actual strings are quite long and I will be splitting them in maximum of 4000 character, I scaled down the problem for better clarity.

Comment: I have added the OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) but the query never stops executing, could you please advise on this?

Comment: After the first "from CTE", you have to add "where len(rest) > 0" to stop the recursion.